# Work with two VBEs at once

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, vbe

I've just taken over maintenance of some pretty scary legacy vba at work. When I have spare time I'm essentially restructuring and rewriting it in new templates. Every now and then, I've managed to exploit a glitch of sorts and have two different instances of the VBE open at once. I don't know exactly what I did to make this happen, but it makes my life much easier, so I'm wondering if anyone else knows. I assume it's something to do with running Word as a new instance, but I can't change my file type settings on my work PC.

Edit: I usually copy and paste into Excel and do it this way, but this is not ideal because I also use a lot of Excel macros for other parts of my job

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.Run` to execute code in another VBA host, and you can step into the code *across* the VBEs.

```
Sub CallExcelUDFFromNonExcelHost()

  'Get an existing instance of Excel
  Dim appXL As Excel.Application
  Set appXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

  'Get the already opened Excel workbook
  Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
  Set wbk = appXL.Workbooks("MyExcelFunctions.xlsm")

  'Call the function in the Excel workbook
  Dim result
  result = appXL.Run(wbk.VBProject.Name & ".MyFunction", "Some Argument")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Word through code:

```
Dim ws As Object

Set ws = CreateObject("word.application")
ws.Visible = True
```

You should get a second instance.